# Energy of a signal

Tags: signal, energy

In signal analysis we work out the energy of a signal. We get a number and thats the end of the story, but theres no explanation of what it means in practise. If it was just some abstract mathematical operation then it would be fine but because its called energy which is a real physical thing I just want to clear up to how it relates to energy in the real world.

Lets just say we have a signal and its calculated energy is 2 Joules.

Assuming everything is ideal and 100% efficient. Does this just tell us that.

We need to burn 2 Joules worth of coal to turn the generator to generate this signal?

And that if we fed this signal into a heater it would generate 2 Joules worth of heat? (0.001053130152932 celsius according to an online Joule to Celsius calculator)

...Just 2 examples I thought of, but is this what "energy" of a signal is telling us?

Comment: Don't you mean the signal's **entropy** instead of its energy?

Comment: No, energy is what I mean. The heat example is just an example...

Comment: The standard calculation for energy of a signal isn't in joules until you account for the impedance of the medium (like you would have to do, and you did not, when converting joules to Celsius, to do so requires knowledge of the medium). After that energy is energy.

Comment: Also, as an aside, don't put things in quotes to emphasize them. It's not ironic energy.

Comment: @Samuel, Your comment could be posted as an answer.

Comment: Also, converting joules to temperature requires a mass and its specific heat.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Im just asking for an explanation of what energy of a signal represents

Comment: @binarysmacker It's probably the horrid conversion directly from joules to Celsius. It, among the general meandering of your writing, displays a lack of understanding that likely indicates you didn't do any research yourself.

Comment: Like I said I just used a joules to celsius converter online and put in 2 joules.

Comment: @binarysmacker No, you probably used a joules to Celsius heat unit converter. Which is the same misunderstanding you had with the original question, 'Celsius heat unit' != 'Celsius'.

Comment: Ah yes your right! It seems theres a lot of information on working all these numbers out but theres not much explaining physical what they mean or how they all relate together. The thing I have learnt is that that energy of a signal != energy in joules. So for me ive learnt something from all this. Surely you can see the confusing in my post if people are saying its all not very clear?

Comment: @binarysmacker I have no idea what you just asked, but I'm glad you've learned something. Remember that the most important part of learning EE (or nearly anything else) is to learn *how* to learn. Pay attention to the details and do not discard adjectives. Also, your != you're :)

Answer (score 2):

The [standard calculation for energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_%28signal_processing%29) of a signal isn't in joules until you account for the impedance of the medium (like you would have to do, and you did not, when converting joules to Celsius, to do so requires knowledge of the medium). After that, energy is energy.

Comment: So what does energy mean in terms of signals. Like I say, its always just calculated and you get an answer but what does it represent? So really would it be better if it wasnt actually called energy as its not the same as energy in joules?

Comment: I suppose that's why it's called 'energy of a signal' and only after accounting for the impedance is it called just 'energy'. I would recommend silently noting disagreement with nomenclature rather than disagreeing to the point of having trouble with the material.

Comment: Ok so the answer to my question is that "energy of a signal" is physically different to just "energy" in Joules. A bit more work is needed to turn the energy of a signal into energy in the form of Joules, because of this it also means my 2 examples are invalid?

Comment: @binarysmacker Exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

"energy of a signal" is physically different to just "energy" in Joules, it is its own thing. A bit more work is needed to turn the energy of a signal into energy in the form of Joules, because of this it also means my 2 examples are invalid

Answer (score 1):

Power is volts multiplied by amps and power is the rate at which energy is taken i.e. 1 joule per second is 1 watt of power. This means there are two signals associated with energy, namely voltage and current. This means you don't work out the energy of a signal because energy comprises two signals. One can usually be inferred from the other but strictly speaking energy does not reside entirely in either voltage or current just like a spinning flywheel's energy is not entirely defined by its rotational speed or mass.